# iterating over a list of dictionaries with a for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

[image]
I have a variable that looks like this, it contains multiple lists and each list has multiple dictionaries. what i need to do now is:

1. combine the lists into 1 big list
2. if 2 dictionaries have the same key i need to combine them(keep 1 of the keys and add their values)

i know i need to use a for loop but how do i reference dictionaries inside a list and how do i refernce the lists stored in the variable?

i tried doing something like this:

```
        for list in bigram_lists:
            for list1 in bigram_lists:
                list.append(list1)
```

it gives back the error that dict object has no attribute append
help would be appreciated

Comment: you're planning on appending to the current list being iterated over, I believe that will make an endless loop. And your `list1` should be in `list` not `bigram_lists`. Please provide bigram_lists, and expected output

Comment: @depperm that's not true, the list is evaluated once by the for loop, so it will only iterate over the initial elements of the list. Please do not use `list` as a variable name since it's a built in keyword in python.

Comment: bigram_lists is too big to post on this website, but its the same kind of variable as x presented above

Comment: @TitouanL I assumed their second loop was meant to be `for list1 in list` which would mean this is an endless loop.

Comment: x as presented is not valid python, is the pending edit correct?

Comment: the for loop should work but i think it doesnt because the lists have dictionaries inside them

Comment: Wouldn't it be more logical to have a single dictionary with multiple keys instead of a lot of dictionaries with 1 key each ??? @BrahimEssadiki

Comment: the multiple dictionaries are a result of the specific coding i needed to use to create the lists. i can merge the dictionaries later but only after i combine the lists first

Comment: @depperm the variable isnt the problem here, python accepts it. it's working with the variable thats a pain.

Answer (score 1):

```
import ast

x = "[{'a': 1850}, {'b': 397}, {'c': 811}, {'d': 990}, {'e': 3198}, {'f': 605}, {'g': 435}, {'h': 1339}, {'i': 1904}, {'j': 59}, {'k': 138}, {'l': 946}, {'m': 652}, {'n': 1691}, {'o': 1813}, {'p': 510}, {'q': 13}, {'r': 1469}, {'s': 1695}, {'t': 2322}, {'u': 516}, {'v': 285}, {'w': 353}, {'x': 49}, {'y': 393}, {'z': 23}] [{'a': 3815}, {'b': 716}, {'c': 1989}, {'d': 1904}, {'e': 5429}, {'f': 908}, {'g': 836}, {'h': 1902}, {'i': 3340}, {'j': 42}, {'k': 148}, {'l': 1818}, {'m': 1156}, {'n': 3782}, {'o': 3365}, {'p': 992}, {'q': 98}, {'r': 2683}, {'s': 3125}, {'t': 3708}, {'u': 1123}, {'v': 335}, {'w': 399}, {'x': 153}, {'y': 706}, {'z': 85}] [{'a': 5087}, {'b': 823}, {'c': 1949}, {'d': 2366}, {'e': 6904}, {'f': 1322}, {'g': 1128}, {'h': 2756}, {'i': 3754}, {'j': 138}, {'k': 346}, {'l': 2709}, {'m': 1618}, {'n': 4391}, {'o': 4675}, {'p': 1321}, {'q': 74}, {'r': 3681}, {'s': 3554}, {'t': 5438}, {'u': 1658}, {'v': 519}, {'w': 1012}, {'x': 128}, {'y': 718}, {'z': 53}]"

strs = x.replace(']','],')[:-1]
strs = "[" + strs + "]"
listOfLists = ast.literal_eval(strs)

finalDict = {}
for ls in listOfLists:
    for dct in ls:
        if (list(dct.keys())[0]) in finalDict:
            finalDict[list(dct.keys())[0]] += dct[list(dct.keys())[0]]
        else:
            finalDict[list(dct.keys())[0]] = dct[list(dct.keys())[0]]

print(finalDict)
```

gives you

```
{'a': 10752, 'b': 1936, 'c': 4749, 'd': 5260, 'e': 15531, 'f': 2835, 'g': 2399, 'h': 5997, 'i': 8998, 'j': 239, 'k': 632, 'l': 5473, 'm': 3426, 'n': 9864, 'o': 9853, 'p': 2823, 'q': 185, 'r': 7833, 's': 8374, 't': 11468, 'u': 3297, 'v': 1139, 'w': 1764, 'x': 330, 'y': 1817, 'z': 161}
```

Comment: Be careful naming your variables, `dict` is a [built in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) keyword in python.

Comment: @TitouanL good point. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: strs = bigram_lists.replace(']', '],')[:-1]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'                                                                        i often get this error, how do i fix this?

Comment: You are trying to use `string` function on a `list`. Maybe try to answer our questions about your initial data, so we can provide a complete and working solution.

Comment: dictionaries.def bigram_frequentie(txt):        
alphabet=list()
file=open(txt, 'r')
text=file.read().lower()
bigrams=[]
for letter in alphabet:
for letter2 in alphabet:
bigrams.append(letter + letter2)
bigram_list=[]
for bigram in bigrams:
bigramcount=re.findall(bigram,text)
bigram_dictionary={bigram:len(bigramcount)}
bigram_list.append(bigram_dictionary)
return bigram_list
def bigram_frequency(taal):
languages=["dutch", "english", "french", "italian", "german", "spanish"]
if taal in languages:
for i in range(10):
j=i+1
bigram_lists=bigram_frequentie(taal + str(j) +'.txt')

Comment: idk how this helps, i've already mentioned the kind of variable x(bigram-lists) is

Comment: I agree with @TitouanL. We do not know what bigram-lists look like. Try to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And do not accept an (my) answer if it does not answer your question.

Comment: @Pedrinho the variable x that i described in my original post is part of the variable bigram_lists, thats why i shared that instead of the entire variable which is too long

Answer (score 1):

Working with `x` as a list of lists, I created a dictionary with multiple keys, that you can split if you want later, but each key has the addition of the same key in each list :

```
result = {}
for sublist in x:
    for elem in sublist:
        for key, value in elem.items():
            if key not in result:
                result[key] = value
            else:
                result[key] += value
```

```
>>> print(result)
{'a': 10752, 'b': 1936, 'c': 4749, 'd': 5260, 'e': 15531, 'f': 2835, 'g': 2399, 'h': 5997, 'i': 8998, 'j': 239, 'k': 632, 'l': 5473, 'm': 3426, 'n': 9864, 'o': 9853, 'p': 2823, 'q': 185, 'r': 7833, 's': 8374, 't': 11468, 'u': 3297, 'v': 1139, 'w': 1764, 'x': 330, 'y': 1817, 'z': 161}
```

Comment: for key, value in elem.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'                                                                                           i understand the function, but i get this error message, is there a package i need to install?

Comment: This only answers the second question. @Brahim you first need to convert the string into a list of lists. Look at my answer how to do that

Comment: 'Convert the string' ? The question doesnt mention strings at all, maybe consider providing a little sample of your data, but containing every possible value.

Comment: `collections.Counter` would work even better

Answer (score 0):

Having corrected the x input as a list of lists:

```
x = [[{'a': 1850}, {'b': 397}, {'c': 811}, {'d': 990}, {'e': 
3198}, {'f': 605}, {'g': 435}, {'h': 1339}, {'i': 1904}, {'j': 
59}, {'k': 138}, {'l': 946}, {'m': 652}, {'n': 1691}, {'o': 
1813}, {'p': 510}, {'q': 13}, {'r': 1469}, {'s': 1695}, {'t': 
2322}, {'u': 516}, {'v': 285}, {'w': 353}, {'x': 49}, {'y': 393}, 
{'z': 23}],

[{'a': 3815}, {'b': 716}, {'c': 1989}, {'d': 1904}, {'e': 5429}, 
{'f': 908}, {'g': 836}, {'h': 1902}, {'i': 3340}, {'j': 42}, 
{'k': 148}, {'l': 1818}, {'m': 1156}, {'n': 3782}, {'o': 3365}, 
{'p': 992}, {'q': 98}, {'r': 2683}, {'s': 3125}, {'t': 3708}, 
{'u': 1123}, {'v': 335}, {'w': 399}, {'x': 153}, {'y': 706}, 
{'z': 85}],

[{'a': 5087}, {'b': 823}, {'c': 1949}, {'d': 2366}, {'e': 6904}, 
{'f': 1322}, {'g': 1128}, {'h': 2756}, {'i': 3754}, {'j': 138}, 
{'k': 346}, {'l': 2709}, {'m': 1618}, {'n': 4391}, {'o': 4675}, 
{'p': 1321}, {'q': 74}, {'r': 3681}, {'s': 3554}, {'t': 5438}, 
{'u': 1658}, {'v': 519}, {'w': 1012}, {'x': 128}, {'y': 718}, 
{'z': 53}]]
```

this:

```
R=[]
for ld in x:
    result = {}
    for d in ld:
        result.update(d)
    R.append(result)

D = dict.fromkeys(R[0].keys(), 0)

for d in R:
    for k in R[0].keys():
        D[k]+=d[k]
```

will give you the answer you wanted.

Comment: What's `L` ? If it's a typo and you meant `x`, then you are calling `.keys()` on the nested lists and not on the dictionaries, Which leads to `AttributeError`

Comment: Thank you, the L line was a not intented to be there.